# How to write my nested structures as List of String rather than List of List of String?

Tags: r, list, data-structures

I have a basic R question. I am building a list output with the following structure:

```
headerSpec <- list()
headerSpec$Statistics$columns <- list("item1", "item2", "item3")
headerSpec$Statistics$color = "#C6E0B4"
```

My expectation when this is exported (via JSON) is a data structure that looks something like this:

```
headerSpec: {
  Statistics: [
    columns: [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
    ],
    color: "#C6E0B4"
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, my data is instead coming through as:

```
headerSpec: {
  Statistics: [
    columns: [
      [
        "item1"
      ],
      [
        "item2"
      ],
      [
        "item3"
      ]
    ],
    color: [
      "#C6E0B4"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Or, to put it more simply, the items which I expect to be String data type are instead List of String (with single element, the String value). I am non-native to R so I apologize if terminology is not right.

How do I write these items to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `jsonlite` to export you can use the `auto_unbox` option:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(headerSpec, auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"Statistics":{"columns":["item1","item2","item3"],"color":"#C6E0B4"}}
```

Comment: Awesome - both answers worked but this one required minimal code changes

Answer (score 1):

Try unlisting your list into a character vector:

```
headerSpec <- list()
headerSpec$Statistics$columns <- list("item1", "item2", "item3")
headerSpec$Statistics$color = "#C6E0B4"

headerSpec$Statistics$columns <- unlist(headerSpec$Statistics$columns)
```